# How to get touch pad up, down, left and right touches from Samsung gear vr?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, touch, gear-vr, touchpad

I am trying to get touches on left , right , up and down touches of Samsung Gear vr touch pad (which is given at right side of Gear vr)

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(button))
{
displayText.text = "Track pad touch down";
}
else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(button))
{
displayText.text = "Track pad touch up";
}
```

When I tried above code for each touch down and touch up I am getting the out put but I need for particular buttons left ,right , up ,down and center.

I want something like this

```
if(Input.touchpad.left)
{
displayText.text = "left button clicked"
}
else if(Input.touchpad.right)
{
displayText.text = "right button clicked"
}
```

//and same for up , down and the middle button also.
Any suggestion will be appreciated , thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the latest GearVR (black one), the headset touchpad doesn't have buttons but rather one single capacitive area.

You can retrieve which area you are touching with **OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis2D.PrimaryTouchpad)**, store it then process the touch with **OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Touch.PrimaryTouchpad)**.

further documentation about Oculus input is available [here](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-ovrinput/).

Comment: Hi , thanks for your suggestion , with the given info I tried this code
    Vector2 touchOut = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis2D.PrimaryTouchpad);
    double tX = Math.Round(touchOut.x, 1);
    double ty = Math.Round(touchOut.y, 1);
    vectorText.text = "x: " + tX + ", y:" + ty;
Based on x and y values I got up , down , left and right clicks.
Thank you!!!